# Django: Count by day, with 0 for days with no records

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-aggregation

I want to get the count of records over 14 days

I'm currently doing:

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    ...
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

all_invitations = Invitation.objects.all()

days14 = all_invitations.filter(start_date__range=[today - timedelta(days=7), today + timedelta(days=8)]).annotate(day=TruncDay('start_date')).values('day').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('day', 'count').order_by('day')
```

However, this does not give me the days for which there are 0 invitations. 
How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

> However, this does not give me the days for which there are 0 invitations.

You have already grouped on `day` before calculating the count

```
....values('day').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

So these days will only be the ones which are present in the table and hence it doesn't include the days with 0 invitations.

I am not sure if this can fully be achieved through a query because the days you want are not present in the table. You could however do following:

- get all the days in 14 days range in a set (s1)
- get the days which are present in table within that 14 days range in another set (s2)
- take the set difference of s1 and s2.

Comment: So what should I do here instead?